# How do I get automated push notifications on firebase database update?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

I know this is a duplicate post, but I have checked the other SO posts as well as the Firebase documentation. Still I can't seem to get my head around how to create a simple `cloud function` that automatically sends `push notifications` on `firebase database` changes (When a new `child` is created).

I have set up all the required steps for `push notifications` in Xcode. And I have successfully sent manual notifications using `pusher` and `firebase`. It works like a charm. But can't seem to get it to work automatically. If this is my database: [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj42H.png) then what should the `cloud function` look like? Are there additional steps to be taken besides writing the function?